# Was my Facebook wall POST successful?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I can post on my friends wall after authenticating the Facebook Graph Explorer (or any app with publish_stream permission for that matter).

[Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

However, how can I validate in my app that the message has actually posted successfully to my friends wall? In some cases, I can go to my friends page and see my message appear, however, in other cases, I notice that there is no message on their wall.

In either case, Facebook returns an object id, like:
[100002349949136_184284371659893](http://graph.facebook.com/100002349949136_184284371659893)

Yet, when I view these posts on the graph (link above), they both return false... The rules of my app require that a message is posted on another user's wall.

**How can I validate that a message appears on a Facebook wall? Or how can I filter user's who have restricted 3rd party apps from posting on their walls?**

Answer (score 0):

The post must be publicly viewable if you're attempting to read the post without an app access token. If it is not publicly viewable, then you must have read_stream permission set in the app you're attempting to read the post with.

Here is the documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/